# Is it possible to deploy NodeJs REST API in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: node.js, rest, google-cloud-platform

I am creating a REST API using NodeJS. How can I host or deploy my API? If it is not possible in Google Cloud Platform, then what are other better possibilities?

Comment: Very possible, and a lot of documentation exists online on how to accomplish this. Try google.

Comment: do mean using google app engine to deploy my nodejs rest api?

Answer (score 0):

I deployed in Heroku. It is way much easier than deploying in Google App Engine.